# How is google's alternative to awt and swing in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt

I use swing now for my GUIs in Java, and I was wondering about the quality of gwt.  Are there compatibility issues with some things (I have a hard time with serialization sometimes when using swing, as an example), is the interface intuitive?  How is the performance?

Comment: You do know that gwt is for making guis for browsers right? So you can't really compare it to swing/awt

Comment: I am primarily interested in Applets, and I use swing for my applets.  In that regard, I don't see how it isn't comparable to swing.

Mind you, I haven't used gwt, so I don't know myself.  Part of why I asked this question to begin with.

Comment: You can't use gwt with applets at all. Gwt is used with googles java to javascript compiler, and can't be used with suns java compiler.

Comment: Right.  But what I'm saying is, whether it's javascript or an applet included in the html code for my site, its some program running on a website.  I just want an objective comparison between the two.  Also how difficult is it to change existing interfaces to gwt in your code?

Comment: I don't get why the downvotes, maybe the question looks a little bit uninformed, but it's a good GWT beginners question after all.

Answer (score 8):

Swing and AWT are for desktop applications. GWT is for web applications. They're not comparable at all.

Comment: They are both GUI APIs so they can be compared as to how easy it is to devlop the same kind of front end. (that is, you can ignore the obvious differences like a web app is easier to deploy, but you have better/faster control over screen elements in a desktop app).

Answer (score 3):

GWT is not just a GUI toolkit, it is a complete framework including a Java to JavaScript compiler, for writing Java code to be compiled into JavaScript and run by the browser. It includes support for serialization and other nice things, but it doesn't support the entire Java language/API. (No reflection for example).

Java applets are really just Java applications running within the browser. Applets don't really integrate with the HTML document model, and (Applet's) don't describe their GUI using html.

For doing GUI development: GWT does all its layout in the HTML DOM modul(Like you would if you wrote the JavaScript yourself) so to do layout you need to understand how HTML and CSS work.

Using GWT for GUIs are very different from using Swing/AWT exactly because you need to describe the GUI using HTML/CSS elements.

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  It explained a lot.

Would you say that a similar application displayed in a browser as a Java applet would have significantly lower performance than the javascript generated by gwt?

Comment: Well I would guess the java applet would load slower, but once fulled loaded, the java applet code should be much faster then the gwt javascript code for most thing.